# Acra missing LOGCAT when logcatArguments is specified in the crash report

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, acra

I am not getting the LOGCAT when the logcatArguments is specified.

I have used the below code

```
@ReportsCrashes(mailTo = Constants.MAIL_TO,

logcatArguments = { "-t", "500", "-v", "long", "ActivityManager:I", "*:D", "*:S" },
        customReportContent = {
                ReportField.BUILD, ReportField.USER_APP_START_DATE, ReportField.USER_CRASH_DATE,
                ReportField.USER_EMAIL, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
                ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE,
                ReportField.LOGCAT,
        },
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG, resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text,
        resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text, resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info,
        resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title,
        resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt,
        resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast, logcatFilterByPid = true)
```

I have tried 
logcatArguments = { "-t", "500", "-v", "long"} as well, still the LOGCAT is empty. But if I do not specify the logcatArguements, I am getting few lines of log. I need to get at leastthe last 500 lines of he Logcat without any filtering. Could someone please help me on how to do the configuration.

Comment: Why do you need to filter the logcat?

Comment: I dont need to filter the logcat. I just need the logcat to with minimum 500 lines of log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just initialize **ACRA** in application file and it give full logcat error.When i send it to mail.

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "1sCVh3QRentB2aK-2lqbjtt92RwFBxEtM2MbOaB9ErRc", mailTo = "your mail", mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST, resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
    ACRA.init(this);
    super.onCreate();

}
}
```

Thanks hope this help you.

Comment: formKey is removed according to this comment.. https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/282#issuecomment-111275619

Comment: So, you didn't get any thing in your crash report ?

Comment: I have changed the initialisation ACRA.init(this); from attachBaseContext() to onCreate() and it worked!!! Thanks Saveen...

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: FOr the record: formKey was removed because Google Docs did not want users of ACRA to store crash reports in them. It says more about that in the wiki

Comment: @LunarWatcher pls the link where you get it

Comment: This happened a while ago. Fetching the link for you.

Comment: The text at the bottom [here](http://www.acra.ch/) and was implemented in [this update](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/ChangeLog#acra-460rc1-8-jan-2015). It is possible formkey is still there, but it isn't used

Answer (score 2):

`"ActivityManager:I", "*:D", "*:S"` are filters. Just remove them. Add `*:V` instead.

Comment: I have removed the filters but still the LOGCAT is empty.         logcatArguments = { "-t", "500", "-v", "long",  "*:V" },